# RXJS. Lazy observable

Tags: javascript, rxjs, reactive-programming

I'm playing around with `rxjs` trying to understand one concept: reactive programming supposed to be lazy. If no one subscriber is attached to an observable, it shouldn't produce values. Here is my example:

```js
const Rx = require('rxjs')

const state = new Rx.Subject()

const changeStateLazy = (args) =>
    Rx.Observable.of(args)
        // some logic, e.g. REST requests
        .do(val => state.next('new state'))

changeStateLazy(42)

const stateListener = state.subscribe(
    val => console.log('state.next: ', val),
    err => console.log('state.error: ', err),
    () => console.log('state.complete'))
```

How to make the observable (which in function `changeStateLazy`) lazy, i.e. run `some logic...` and change the state only if a listener is attached to `state` subject (in my case it's `stateListener`)?

Comment: Why do you need to do this? What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: @cartant No problems, just learning rx and can't accomplish lazy state changing

Comment: If you want to take action upon or be informed of (un)subscriptions, you can wrap it in another observable: `Observable.create(observer => { /*observer subscribed*/ const subscription = subject.subscribe(observer); return () => { /*observer unsubscribed*/ subscription.unsubscribe(); }; });`

Comment: @cartant can you make an answer from the commend above and elaborate a bit? I couldn't make it's working for my case

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I could manage that.

```
const Rx = require('rxjs')

const lazyStateModifier = new Rx.ReplaySubject(1)
    .map(args => {
        console.log('>some logic. args: ', args)
        return {status: 'OK', result: 'new state'}
    })
    .map(res => res.result)

const state = new Rx.Subject().merge(lazyStateModifier)

const changeStateLazy = (args) =>
    lazyStateModifier.next(args)

console.log('>invoke changeStateLazy')
changeStateLazy(42)

console.log('>subscribe')
state.subscribe(
    val => console.log('state.next: ', val),
    err => console.log('state.error: ', err),
    () => console.log('state.complete'))
```

Hope there's a better solution, without merging every lazy observable to the state...

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly sure what you want to achieve, but if you want to output the LAST value when an observer is subscribed, try "AsyncSubject".

```
const state = new Rx.AsyncSubject();
```

For AsyncSubject to work, it needs to call the complete method.

```
const changeState = () =>
    Rx.Observable.of(1)
       .subscribe(val => {
          state.next('new state');
          state.complete();
        });
```

You may want to use "BehaviorSubject", "BehaviorSubject", etc. if you want it to behave differently.